# Как занести в базу данных данные из Json файла?

Tags: c#, json, база-данных

У меня есть данные вот в таком Json формате, как я могу занести их в базу?

```
[
  {
    "nmId": 37018690
  },
  {
    "nmId": 9166307
  },
  {
    "nmId": 37012014
  },
  {
    "nmId": 10986641
  },
  {
    "nmId": 17513093
  },
  {
    "nmId": 55275274
  },
  {
    "nmId": 9166302
  }
]
```

У меня есть вот такая модель

```
public class Article
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? nmId { get; set; }
    }
```

И вот такой контекст

```
public class ArticlesContext : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\User\\source\\repos\\ParserSppWb\\ParserSppWb\\ArticleDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: А в чём проблема-то? Считываете, заносите...

Comment: А какой синтаксис должен быть в таком случае?

Comment: Еще забыл написать что у меня эти Json данные в отдельном файле

Comment: EF какой версии?

Comment: спарсить -> `context.Articles.AddRagne(спарсенный массив)` -> `context.SaveChanges()`